# Custom data in Channel and Message level in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

How to keep some custom metadata in channel and message level in the Microsoft teams app?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Prasad-MSFT, is team is supporting custom metadata fields that will hold the values like ex: any text content actually

 We trying to store some JSON objects at the channel and message level graph API calls( i.e custom attributes), which we will use in run time API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your metadata while posting a Adaptive card but there is a limit to create a payload of card. You can read this data while posting the card submit but we can not store data directly in channel.

Comment: is there any API that can help to store metadata eg: like open and Schema Extensions(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview)

Comment: @lakshminarayana -  You can store your metadata using extensions API like: 

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions
Content-type: application/json
{
    "@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
    "extensionName":"com.contoso.roamingSettings",
    "theme":"dark",
    "color":"purple",
    "lang":"Japanese"
}

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-open-users